# SQL query :Copy one table to another from different servers

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, insert

What's wrong with my query, I want to copy three columns to another server\table if one of the column (ID_DIRCT) is not null :

```
INSERT INTO  System\Syst3.Server1.dbo.TABLE_RESRC (NO_EMPLY,PR,NM_FAML,CO_DIRCT)
SELECT NO_EMPLY, PR_EMPLY, NM_EMPLY, ID_DIRCT 
FROM System\Syst3.Server2.dbo.RESRC
WHERE System\Syst3.Server2.dbo.RESRC.ID_DIRCT IS NOT NULL
```

Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server, SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't state wether you are getting an error, or wrong results or anything like that, you don't even say what RDBMS you are using. So, an educated guess of what's wrong with your query is that you are not using quotes to call your linked server (it needs them because of some special chars in the name of the linked server):

```
INSERT INTO  [System\Syst3].Server1.dbo.TABLE_RESRC (NO_EMPLY,PR,NM_FAML,CO_DIRCT)
SELECT NO_EMPLY, PR_EMPLY, NM_EMPLY, ID_DIRCT 
FROM [System\Syst3].Server2.dbo.RESRC A
WHERE A.ID_DIRCT IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The query didnt return anything, was saying there was an error near the "\". I tried your code now and it says this : TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
------------------------------

The statement could not be parsed.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Deferred prepare could not be completed.
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
The multi-part identifier "[System\Syst3].Server2.dbo.RESRC.ID_DIRCT" could not be bound. (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------

Comment: @TommyLeblanc Ok, you should be posting that on your question (along with the RDBMS that you are using, though it seems to be SQL Server). I updated my answer anyway, so you can try again.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server and it's Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. Just tried your new query,TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
------------------------------

This SQL statement is not a query.

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------

Comment: I got it guys, tried my query in VS2008 instead of SQL 2008 R2 and it worked!